# Subtracting values from lists, received "generator object is not subscriptable" error

Tags: python, list, generator-expression

I am trying to subtract the values of two lists from each other. Like this:

```py
    a = [1,2,3,4,5] b = [1,2,3,4,5] 
    a - b = [0,0,0,0,0]
```

However, the loop I'm trying to do it in keeps giving me "generator object is not subscriptable" and refers to this section of my code:

```py
      distances_1 = [a[z] - b[z] for z in x]
```

My sample data differs in dimensions for each file; though, here is an example of what it looks like:

```py
    x = [1.2323 2.5689] y = [2.3565 3.58789]
```

Here is an example of my code:

```py
    def distances_z(x,y):
    dct = {}
    for i in y:
        a = (i.split(' ',)[0] for i in y)
        for z in x:
            b = (z.split(' ',1)[0] for z in x)
            distances_1 = [a[z] - b[z] for z in x]
            return distances_1
        dct[i +"_"+"list"] = [distances_1]
    print(dct)
    return dct
```

I believe it to be a problem with my `a` and `b` variables not being recognized as integers. I have tried converting them to floats using `float()`, but it does not work.

Comment: You assign generators (by generator expressions) to a and b. Use e. g. `list(a)` to create a list from the generator or just use a list comprehension instead of generator expression.

Comment: currently `a` and `b` are generators since you used parentheses. use brackets to make them list comprehensions. see [generator expressions vs list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47789/13138364)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5] 
b = [1,2,3,4,5] 
c = [x[0] - x[1] for x in zip(a,b)]
```

Gives output

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```